# webpack entry filename config used [ext] placeholders not take effect

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm sorry for my English is low,hope you understand.
I learning how to use webpack build my project.The following is config for two entry files:

```js
 entry:{
    main: {
      import: "./src/main.js",
      filename:"main/[name].[hash:6][ext]",
      dependOn:"lodash"
    },
    index:{
      import:"./src/index.js",
      filename:"index/[name].[hash:6][ext]",
      dependOn:"lodash"
    },
    lodash: {import: [ "lodash" ],filename:"lodash/[name].[hash:6].js" }
  },
```

I think it will generator two files after I execute the `npm run build` script,for example,`main.a24fc1.js` and `index.b42afd.js` ,their name should look like that.

But in result they is this:

```markdown
|- build
  |- index
    |- index.81c047[ext]
  |- main
    |- main.81c047[ext]
```

In their `filename` config,used `[ext]` placeholders but it's not take effect.I don't know why it happended,becouse my config the same as in webpack document's demo.

```js
// This is webpack demo config:
module.exports = {
  //...
  entry: {
    app: './app.js',
    home: { import: './contact.js', filename: 'pages/[name][ext]' },
    about: { import: './about.js', filename: 'pages/[name][ext]' },
  },
};
```

I are unable solve the problem...Thank to everyone helped me!(Please tell me if there are has any English mistakes in this article.^_^)

Answer (score 1):

You have specified the output to be `main/[name].[hash:6][ext]` hence the folder structure. Just specify it as `[name].[hash:6].js` and you will get your desired structure.

```
entry:{
    main: {
      import: "./src/main.js",
      filename:"[name].[hash:6].js",
      dependOn:"lodash"
    },
    index:{
      import:"./src/index.js",
      filename:"[name].[hash:6].js",
      dependOn:"lodash"
    },
    lodash: {import: [ "lodash" ],filename:"[name].[hash:6].js" }
},
```

Note that the `filename` property in the `entry` block is extracted from `output.filename`([Source](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/#output-filename)) which does not support `[ext]`. ([Source](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#template-strings) - Table - Substitutions available on File-level)

Comment: Thank you for helping me.Your meaning is cannot use `[ext]` placeholders in the `filename` of entry file config for get `.js` extension ? Why in webpack official website document demo's config is that? I know use `[name].[hash:6].js` is  able make sure I get `.js` extension,but I now want use `[ext]` get the . Thank you again.

Comment: @HiHighCoder that's actually a valid question !! It might be that the documentation example is wrong.